# How to avoid URIBuilder to encode comma to "%2C" or other characters in query params

Tags: java, apache, http, uri, urlencode

I would like to create a URI using apache class `org.apache.http.client.utils.URIBuilder` and I need to not encode query params to percent-encoding.

```
import org.apache.http.HttpEntity;
import org.apache.http.HttpHost;
import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.client.HttpClient;
import org.apache.http.client.config.RequestConfig;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPost;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpRequestBase;
import org.apache.http.client.utils.URIBuilder;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.HttpClientBuilder;
import org.apache.http.util.EntityUtils;

import java.net.URI;


public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

        RequestConfig config = RequestConfig.custom().build();

        HttpClientBuilder builder = HttpClientBuilder.create().setDefaultRequestConfig(config);

//        URI url = new URI("http://some-website.com/?range=10,20");
//        If url is created with the line above the comma "," is not encoded when sending the request
//        When you use URIBuilder the comma "," is converted to "%2C"

        URIBuilder uribuilder = new URIBuilder("http://some-website.com/");

        uribuilder.addParameter("range", "10,20");

        URI url = uribuilder.build();

        System.out.println("URL => " + url.toString());


        HttpHost targetHost = new HttpHost(url.getHost(), url.getPort(), url.getScheme());

        HttpClient client = builder.build();

        HttpRequestBase req = new HttpPost(url);


        HttpResponse httpResponse = client.execute(targetHost, req);

        HttpEntity entity = httpResponse.getEntity();

        String responseString = EntityUtils.toString(entity, "UTF-8");

        System.out.println(responseString);
        System.out.println("Finished");
    }
}
```

Is there a way to do that using the `URIBuilder` class like some flag I don't know?

I would appreciate other suggests (maybe better ways than my code) to accomplish this. But I can't send the characters in query string encoded.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: How about `uribuilder.setCustomQuery("range=10,20");`

Comment: @Mafor Can I loop a Map<string, string> to add query strings using this method you refer? I mean, I would need to build the all the query string before doing this, right?

Comment: That's right, you won't be able to add parameters one by one anymore. But I don't think there is any other option if you want to use URIBuilder.

Comment: Are you still having this issue. You can try to use `URIBuilder.of(full_path)`. I tested it, seems working without encoded characters